# Plotly - how to change x axis labels in python?

Tags: python, plotly

I am plotting a horizontal stacked bar chart, and I want each item on the x axis to reflect a datetime value instead of an integer. I am plotting the values in terms of seconds. How can I change the x axis tick labels to reflect a datetime? Thanks!

```
import plotly.plotly as plt
import plotly.graph_objs as gph

data = [
    ('task 1', 300),
    ('task 2', 1200),
    ('task 3', 500)
]
traces = []
for (key, val) in data:
    traces += [gph.Bar(
        x=val,
        y=1,
        name=key,
        orientation='h',
        )]

layout = gph.Layout(barmode='stack')
fig = gph.Figure(data=traces, layout=layout)
plt.iplot(fig)
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example ([docs](https://plot.ly/python/figure-labels/))

```
layout = gph.Layout(
    title='Plot Title',
    xaxis=dict(
        title='x Axis',
        titlefont=dict(
            family='Courier New, monospace',
            size=18,
            color='#7f7f7f'
        )
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        title='y Axis',
        titlefont=dict(
            family='Courier New, monospace',
            size=18,
            color='#7f7f7f'
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 4):

In your layout you need to specify the type to be category as well as specify the categoryorder and array values.  Also in order to get your bar charts to print properly they need to be arrays.  The code below seems to do what you would like it to do - given the fact that your datetime is the value.

```
import plotly.plotly as plt
import plotly.graph_objs as gph

data = [
    ('task 1', 300),
    ('task 2', 1200),
    ('task 3', 500)
]
vals = []
traces = []
for (key, val) in data:
    vals.append(val)
    traces.append(gph.Bar(
        x=[val],
        y=[1],
        name=key,
        ))

layout = gph.Layout(xaxis=dict(categoryorder='array', categoryarray=vals, type="category"))
fig = gph.Figure(data=traces, layout=layout)
plt.iplot(fig)
```